# Python Export CSV file but file still keeps brackets and quotes

Tags: python

I'm trying to export a list from python into a CSV. However, I still get quotes and brackets from the csv file. I only just want the data.

```
import csv


fileName = "test.csv"
headers = ("Unit 1", "Result")
data = ["column 1", "column 2"], ["row 1", "row 2"]

with open (fileName, "a", newline="") as d:
    csv.writer(d, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    d.write(f"{headers}\n")
    for line in data:   
        d.write(f"{line}\n")
print("Exported the file " + fileName + ".")
d.close()
```

Example of what I want the CSV file to show

> ```
> Unit 1     Result
> Column 1   Column 2
> Row 1      Row 2
> ```

Comment: Your output is not actually a CSV file, of course. Wondering how useful this form of output would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a csv writer but didn't use it. Write rows through the writer.

```
import csv

fileName = "test.csv"
headers = ("Unit 1", "Result")
data = ["column 1", "column 2"], ["row 1", "row 2"]

with open (fileName, "a", newline="") as d:
    writer = csv.writer(d, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(data)

print("Exported the file " + fileName + ".")
```